# Customize Input validation

Tags: javascript, php

I have a JavaScript validation on form, every time the form is submitted it will empty the boxes. I need to change it, when the form is filled up incomplete with empty boxes. it will not clear all the fields after button click. All fields will be clear only when filled up completely.

Here's my script;

```
$("#sub").click( function() {
    $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"), 
        $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(), 
        function(info){ $("#result").html(info); }
    );
    clearInput();
});
$("#myForm").submit( function() {
    return false;   
});

function clearInput() {
    $("#myForm :input").each( function() {
        $(this).val('');
    });
}
```

Comment: You can write a `Validation` function and if `true`, call function `clearInput`

Comment: sorry Rajesh but I have difficulty figuring it out. thanks for the reply

Comment: Also just a pointer. Call clearInput inside success of post.

Answer (score 0):

Following is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7m0b6rjd/) depicting a simple  validation.

#### Code

```js
function submit() {
    if (validate()) {
        // Post Request call
        clearInput();
    }
}

function validate() {
    var valid = true;
    if ($("#txt1").val().length == 0) {
        valid = false;
    }
    if ($("#txt2").val().length == 0) {
        valid = false;
    }
    if ($("#txt3").val().length == 0) {
        valid = false;
    }
    console.log(valid)
    return valid;
}

function clearInput() {
    $("#txt1").val("");
    $("#txt2").val("");
    $("#txt3").val("");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt1">
<input type="text" id="txt2">
<input type="text" id="txt3">
<button onclick="submit()">submit</button>
```

Hope this helps!